# Mock requests.Session.get in a nested context manager

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking, python-unittest

I want to mock a function that uses a `requests.Session` object, which was created in a context manager, to perform a `get` request, again using a context manager. So there are two context managers involved.

Here's an example code:

```py
# main.py

from requests import Session

def fun(session):
    with session.get("https://httpstat.us/200") as response:
        print(response)

        
def run():
    with Session() as session:
        fun(session)

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

When executed, the status code of `200` is printed as expected.

Now I want to mock the get request, to return a different value. Somehow I can't navigate the mess of context managers and return values.

Here's my best effort:

```py
# maintest.py
from unittest.mock import patch
from main import run

def test_main():
    
    with patch("main.Session") as mocked_session:
        mocked_session.__enter__.return_value.get.__enter__.return_value = "MOCKED"
        run()
```

Running the test with pytest, I was hoping to get `"MOCKED"` printed, but instead I get

`<MagicMock name='Session().__enter__().get().__enter__()' id='140303100714240'>`

I've tried any conceivable combination of `__enter__`, `.get` and `.return_value`

Comment: There is no separate reference to `requests` in `main` (that happens only if you use `from...import`), so you have to patch `"requests.Session"` instead of `"main.requests.Session"`.

Comment: Thanks @MrBean Bremen. What if I I change to `from requests import Session` in `main`?

Comment: In this case you would patch `"main.Session"`.

Comment: Thanks @MrBeanBremen, I've implemented your suggestion. Still, I can't seem to get the return value to `get`.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer to clarify how the correct code shall look - too complicated for a comment...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got it almost right, the correct way to mock is:

```py
with patch("main.Session") as mocked_session:
    mocked_session.return_value.__enter__.return_value.get.return_value.__enter__.return_value = "MOCKED"
```

I will break this down for clarification.

Your `session_mock` refers to the `Session` class. To get the `Session` instance, you use `return_value` (as you do for every call).
The `with` statement internally calls `__enter__()` on that session to get the `session` instance, so you have to add `__enter__` for the method and `return_value` for the call.
Now you call `get()` on that object, which by the same logic needs an added `get.return_value`.
And finally, this is used in another `with` statement to create `response`, which again needs an added `__enter__.return_value`.

The result gets you the `response` object for your mocked `Session`, and you can set another value.

If breaking that down in code, it would look something like:

```py
with patch("main.Session") as mocked_session:
    mocked_session_instance = mocked_session.return_value
    mocked_session_object = mocked_session_instance.__enter__.return_value
    mocked_get = mocked_session_object.get.return_value
    mocked_response = mocked_get.__enter__
    mocked_response.return_value = "MOCKED"
```